Help understanding what is wrong in my calculation of this derivative
I’m trying to calculate $f'(0)$ for the function:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{e^{3x} - 7x - \cos(7x)}{x}, & x \neq 0 \\
-4, & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
My approach:
I started with the expression for $f'(0)$:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos7x}{x}+4}{x}$$
Then I split the terms into:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos7x}{x^2}+\frac4{x}$$
While the first term works out with L'Hopital's Rule, the second term $\frac4{x}$ diverges, causing the whole limit to diverge. However, the solution says the limit should be $29$.
Question:
Why does splitting the terms lead to divergence, even though $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$? I thought this was valid, but it seems to fail here. Could someone help explain why?

The limit of a sum is the sum of limits... if both exist and are finite.

The first term $\frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos(7x)}{x^2}$ also diverges, which can be shown by applying l'Hopital's rule once. Be careful to not make the mistake of blindly applying l'Hopital's rule a second time, since after the first application you no longer have the indeterminate form $0/0$.

Splitting the limit into $2$ limits like you did is not correct since both of them do not exist individually. Hence, L'Hôpital's Rule/Taylor's Expansion is to be applied directly on the function in the limit.

When you are at: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos7x}{x}+4}{x}$, you should keep everyting in the same fraction:
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos7x}{x}+4}{x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos7x+4x}{x}}{x}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{3x}-3x-\cos7x}{x^2}
\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3e^{3x}-3+7\sin(7x)}{2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3e^{3x}-3}{2x}+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ 7\sin(7x)}{2x}\\&=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{9e^{3x}}{2}+\frac {49} 2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ \sin(7x)}{7x} = \frac 9 2+\frac {49} 2 = 29
\end{aligned}$$
after applying twice  l'Hopital's rule

Sure, I get that, my question is why it breaks if you try to separate it into the two terms?

@Jm_ The equality $$\underset{x \rightarrow 0 }{\text{lim}} \frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos 7x}{x^2}+\frac{4}{x}=\underset{x \rightarrow 0 }{\text{lim}} \frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos 7x}{x^2}+\underset{x \rightarrow 0 }{\text{lim}} ~ \frac{4}{x}$$
is true iff
$$ \underset{x \rightarrow 0 }{\text{lim}} \frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos 7x}{x^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \underset{x \rightarrow 0 }{\text{lim}} ~ \frac{4}{x}$$
exist. Which is not the case here.

@SineoftheTime: You are right. Fixed.

@Jm_: By splitting the limit, you obtain an indetermination $\infty-\infty$ because the two parts diverge. By keeping everything in the same fraction, the 2 terms that diverge happen to sum to $0$, and what remains can converge to a finite limit.

As noticed
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{e^{3x}-7x-\cos7x}{x^2}+\frac4{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{3x}-3x-\cos7x}{x^2}$$
which can be also solved without l'Hospital rule, indeed
$$\frac{e^{3x}-3x-\cos7x}{x^2}=9\frac{e^{3x}-3x-1}{9x^2}+49\frac{1-\cos7x}{49x^2}\to \frac 92+\frac{49}2=29$$
